# MySQL filter query regarding multiple filters

Tags: mysql, search

I'll try and elaborate my question in the simplest form possible. I'm creating an e-commerce website and I'm trying to set up filters for the search result. Everything has been just fine, until I ran into this following issue. When I try to group by id I lose all the other foreign keys to the specification value and if I remove the group by I get a ton of results, each containing own foreign key to the value. (I'm inner joining each article with respective specification values). My question therefore is how do I filter all of these specification ids?

My query (translated and simplified) is as follows:

```
select * from article
left join article_specification on article_specification.fk_articles=article.id 
where (fk_specification_value=172 or fk_specification_value=175 or fk_specification_value=184) 
group by id order by date desc
```

By running this query I get 1 result (hence the group by), however if I don't group I can't really do anything with that result set. If I change the ORS into ANDS in the query, I get nothing, since there is only 1 value. That's the root of my question. Thanks in advance, sorry if my question was a little bit poorly sentenced.

Comment: Please post a sqlfiddle, with the output you expect for the query.

Comment: You are using group by without aggregation function  

and the use of select * with group by  don't have much sense ..

please explain the real result you need for you select and over all  why you use group by   .. eventually  add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want articles that meets *all* specifications, you can do:

```
select a.*
from article a join
     article_specification ars
     on ars.fk_articles = a.id 
where ars.fk_specification_value in (172, 175, 184) 
group by a.id
having count(distinct ars.fk_specification_value) = 3
order by a.date desc;
```

Note:  In general, I discourage the use `select *` with `group by`.  In this case it is okay because `a.id` is (presumably) the primary key in `article`.  In fact, this use of `group by` is supported by the ANSI standard.  However, interpreting the language in the standard requires understanding what a "functional dependency" is.

If you want articles that meet *any* of the specifications, you could use the above query without the `having` clause.  However, an `exists` is more appropriate:

```
select a.*
from article a 
where exists (select 1
              from article_specification ars
              where ars.fk_articles = a.id  and
                    ars.fk_specification_value in (172, 175, 184) 
             );
```

Comment: This is working exactly as I wanted, thank you so much.